# What's the correct way to communicate with packages from app component?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, mvvm

To minimize the team workloads, I created several modules and prepare to publish on NPM as private packages in our organization account.

These packages provide an easy way to render templates following our company branding guidelines.

Since the needs may be different across products and teams, the packages should allow custom data binding through `@Input()` decorator.

I'm not considering to use `Injectable Service` to share data because I think whether to use Redux-like or use a shared service is decided by the application team.

I took time reading following for understanding how UI packages accept data input normally,

1. Angular Material2 (Angular)
2. Atlassian UI Kit (React)
3. Ant Design (React)
4. NGX-Bootstrap (Angular)

However, after reading them, I'm getting confused what method should I adopt for data binding.

Here are two methods to binding data I came up with,

1.
One-by-one data binding which format is like,

```
<component-selector-a mode="_FromComponent" position="_FromComponent" presentation="_dataFromService">
</component-selector-a>
```

**This approach is used by Angular Material2**

2.
Pass the object directly, such as,

```
const config: PackageAConfigInterface = {
    mode:  _mode,
    position:  _position,
    presentation:  _presentation,
}

<component-selector-a [config]="config"> </component-selector-a>
```

**This approach is used by Atlassian UI Kit**

So here is the question,
What's the the correct way for making data passed in by the application?
Or, should I allow both methods and make choice decided by developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would use the `config` approach because it allows for easy usage as well as make the component future-proof in case there are more config properties added in the future.

It also makes it more readable.

Another thing, if you have inputs that control styling I would think about dropping them completely and instead allow each product that uses your component to define the styles from outside the component instead. This also makes it easier in the future if more products have their own use of the component since you won't have to update the component when a new use case comes up.