# Why do most Angular UI components not use an object for configuring Input?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and its ecosystem, including UI kits like Material 2 and ng-zorro.

According to their source code, they use the `@Input` decorator for each allowable config.

This code is from Material 2:

```
@Input() mode: 'push' | 'over' | 'side';
@Input() autoFocus: boolean;
```

And this is from ng-zorro:

```
@Input() nzWidth: number;
@Input() nzCollapsedWidth: number;
```

Actual inputs are more than these, thus, I'm wondering why they don't define an interface or even class and name it `config`, like this:

```
@Input() config: MatSidenavConfig;
```

Ref: 
[What's the correct way to communicate with packages from app component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242249/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-with-packages-from-app-component)

Are there any things we should be concerned about?

=====Update=====

I created a test at StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1o67xy

Using a config object or not for `@Input` are both functional; not sure if I did it wrong.

Comment: This is really personal preference, I don't think there's a best practice on that. I think they do it like that for the intellisense on the selectors : when using an IDE that can read packages, you get the intellisense for all available inputs.

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong, but as far I as have learned, using interface or class is readable for IDE, at least for VS Code (i mean define an object then put the object value in template).

Comment: You got me wrong : in VSCode, if you want to use a component and know its inputs, you will need to install [Angular Language Service](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service). Once done, in your **html** files (not the TS files), you will have intellisense for your components, as well as all of their inputs/ouputs.

Comment: @andyintheloop do you have any link for the same?

Comment: This is used as to give different different changes to component easily think that all fields included in one object and you passing it as a object then you have to pass all data properly but if they are separately passing it will be easy understand in HTML as an example for @Input() autoFocus you can set it value in html as true without creating any object or variable

Comment: The reason is that angular does not handle field changes inside object for input, so you have to do extra logic (ngDoCheck) to handle that by yourself. say, if you pass user object with {name: 'user1'}, and the code reference your component modify name field. So by flattening input, you do not need to worry that.

Comment: @trichetriche I did the test, and Angular Language Service is able to detect object keys, that's awesome, but considering comment from ABOS, ngDoCheck might be their concern

Comment: `ngDoCheck` should not be an issue, as every input is processed by `ngOnChanges` and not `ngDoCheck`.

Comment: @umesh99 I get your point and it's very reasonable, I think this is the DX part.

Comment: @PardeepJain Hi, I'm not sure what links are you referring to

Comment: @trichetriche Hi, I created a test and put it in the updated question, can you check it?

Comment: @ABOS Hi, I created a test and put it in the updated question, can you check it?

Comment: @andyintheloop I've checked it, what do you want us to do besides checking it ?

Comment: @trichetriche I've been studying about life cycle hooks for a while, and this test is basically built for validating what ABOS said.
Without doing the `ngDoCheck` or `ngOnChanges` manually, it sill works.
Perhaps this is not related to current question, but if my test is fair enough to prove `ngDoCheck` is not the issue here.

Comment: Who is ABOS ? And of course it works, but that's because of the Angualr way of handling inputs. I think you're drifting away from your original question here !

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why we don't use an object for the configuration of the input can be found in angular official docs

```
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
```

Angular only calls the hook when the value of the input property changes. Angular doesn’t care that the configurations own property have been changed. The configuration object reference didn’t change so, from Angular’s perspective, there is no change to report!

To solve this issue, 
We need to implement ngDoCheck() it is invoked whenever change detection is run,
That allows us to implement some logic there, like remembering the old values and comparing them against new ones

To simply avoid all this cumbersome logic instead of passing values via object we pass them via primitives.

Hope this helps.